# Java Parser for Asana App Stop working ( Giving no response) without notification and program is in running state

Tags: java, json, asana

I am working on a java utility that fetch all data from ASANA application and parse this data and save it to local database. But when I execute this utility after some time program output stuck but program execution status is running.And pointer is blinking. I don't know what is exact problem. May be ASANA server stop responding, may be network issue, may be utility stop working, may be any other issue. If java utility have any issue or error than exception must be occur but till now this utility gives no exception.
Please help me...

Below is Java utility execution image link in which program's output is stuck but pointer is blinking

http://www.yogile.com/0frw6azk#06587124l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sorry but this is not enough information to troubleshoot the issue here. If you post the code that you have written somebody may be able to identify a loop you have entered. In terms of the Asana API, any request will timeout after 30 seconds so I would suspect this is an issue in your client.

Comment: can I increase timout time?

Comment: A client cannot increase the timeout for an API request on the server. This limit is very similar to timeout limits enforced across the web. I suspect that even though we have closed the connection your code is in a loop and therefore not returning from a function call somewhere. Ultimately, I believe this is a bug in your code and not in the API.